# how to append variable in LIKE in SQL Query

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql

I have a SQL query where I want to append $customerID, how to achieve that?

```
>    SELECT `e`.*, `at_assigned_campus_manager`.`value` AS
> `assigned_campus_manager`, `at_physical_verify`.`value` AS
> `physical_verify` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
> `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_assigned_campus_manager` ON
> (`at_assigned_campus_manager`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
> (`at_assigned_campus_manager`.`attribute_id` = '183') LEFT JOIN
> `customer_entity_int` AS `at_physical_verify` ON
> (`at_physical_verify`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
> (`at_physical_verify`.`attribute_id` = '209') WHERE
> (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_assigned_campus_manager.value 
> **LIKE '"$customerId/%"' )** AND (at_physical_verify.value IS NULL) AND
> (`e`.`group_id` IN(4, 5, 6)) LIMIT ".$page." 50 " 
> 
> 
> getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$customerId'
> (T_VARIABLE)
```

> ```
> Here is the collection  Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
>                                                                       ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname, entity_id')
>                                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('assigned_campus_manager',array('like' => $customerId . '/%'))
>                                                                       ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true),'left')
>                                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4,5,6)))
>                                                                       ->setPage($page,50)
> ```

Comment: send collection code please

Comment: Added in Question

Comment: I assume you are using custom field created in customer                                                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('assigned_campus_manager',array('like' => $customerId . '%')). shall i know where you got $customerID? you writing right  $customerID is right in model. try to use  ->setCurPage($page) 
     ->setPageSize(50);

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname, entity_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('assigned_campus_manager',array('like' =>"{$customerId}/%"))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true),'left')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4,5,6)))
    ->setPage($page,50)
```

Please try it